# Problem with holding id of current clicked post on my webapp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page where i listed a posts from a database and I want to do that when i clicked a specific post it redirect me to another page with blank area where is more details with ID of this post. I don't know how to do that the blank area will which post were clicked. (Sorry for my english)

```
 <div class="row">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($viewmodel as $item) : ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="card shadow">
                                <div class="card-header border-dark shadow"><?php echo $item['TITLE']; ?></div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $item['DESCRITIONS']; ?></p>


                                        <a class="btn badge-secondary btn-sm" type="submit"
                                           href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares/zobaczZadanie">More</a>

                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <small class="text-muted"><?php echo $item['DATE']; ?></small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

But I don't have acces to specific post

Comment: I think what you lack is a link to the post you want to view in detail. I noticed that your index page has multiple links, one for each post probably. Keep the ID of that post on the link. This way you can indicate the post you're trying to fetch through the ID provided on the URI.

Comment: thanks for your response , I will try this solutions :)

Comment: No problem. Get back to me in case you couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I thought about this but i have no idea how to do that . I can put in div id a proper id of specific post but i don't know how to pass id value to my php class where i query datebase. I read about Ajax but it didn;t work for me